# Reload function on http request using observable Angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, rxjs5

I'm tring do build a custom function to reaload my http request every minutes (so don't need to refresh the page)...thanks in advance

So I got a code as bellow:

```
const usersURL = 'http://my.super.url.php'

@Injectable()
export class UserService {



 users: Observable<User[]>

 constructor (public http:Http) {

       this.users = http.get(usersURL)
                      .map(res => [res.json()]);


this.users.subscribe(

usersURL => console.log(usersURL), // Here we catch up the values

() => {}, // Here we catch up errors

() => console.log("completed!") // Here we catch up if its completed
)
 setTimeout(function(){
     this.users.subscribe.reload();
   }, 60000); // Here I'm trying to reload my call to web API every minutes
```

}

}

Comment: Euuuh so, what's the problem? I mean, what isn't working? (also, why are you returning an array with the parsed json response?..)

Comment: I think your are looking for a realtime data service. Why reload data if it has not changed? Please read on WebSockets.

Comment: Thats in the specification the datas has to be realoaded from backend every minutes....and my SeTimeout function is returning an error from the console: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined"

Comment: @MaximeGélinas a realtime dataservice could be such a good idea too...something like Ajax for exemple...could please show me a way to adapt my code maybe?

Comment: @briosheje.. I am returning an array with the parsed json because I am injecting theses datas to the html/views

Comment: @EmileCantero Wich type of server side do you use? For exemple, SignalR is a very popular one for C#.

Comment: @MaximeGélinas the server side is just a php script for me and Node JS is inside to make it works (I know we expect to merge it to apache server later in the project)

Comment: @MaximeGélinas ..that's done I find a way to resolve it using http polling